# Print on roll paper

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

I want to print on a roll paper from chrome. The length of the paper seems to be static, so that roll paper can not be used effectively.

E.g. if we print "Hello world" from:

```
<html>
<body>Hello World</body>
</html>
```

It will print like 27cm length of paper (because paper format is set to A4). Is there a CSS-trick to have a dynamic height in chrome?

**Update**

I am *not* looking for a one-time configuration for a specific length. I am searching for a dynamic page height. Firefox and IE are able to print dynamically, but the chrome virtual print driver seems not to be.

**Update 2**

Just to make it more clear:

[image]

This is what I do **not** want.  The length of the paper should be as height as the content. The content is dynamic.

Comment: The `body` **has** a dynamic height. Check http://jsfiddle.net/a7sk4a2y/

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with css media. Have a look here [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/08/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/]

Comment: You did not fully read the question.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried setting the [`size` property for @page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size) to the actual height of the `<body>` (dynamically through JS)? The outcome will probably depend on various factors, from OS to printer driver, but with a bit of luck that hint might carry over into the print dialog.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but this lead to resizing within the given paper size :( How would you try this?

Comment: Do you tried `vh` units ? http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: this smells like hardware. if your printer can print on roll paper, this should be addressed in printers manual or its program suite. and given an sdk.

Comment: @Chris your post was a long time ago, but I'm still looking for a solution. Due to my dynamic div conent, my printer with paper roll also always prints in A4 format.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming MS Windows as the host environment for the browser, you can tell Chrome to print using the System Print Dialog, you can select the target printer, and set the Preferences. If you then hit the Advanced button, you can select PostScript Custom Page Size and from there, set the size of the'page' it has an option for Continuous Roll paper and allows one to set a page height of up to 5.08 meters.

Here: [image]

Comment: It's about _dynamic_ height!

Comment: I guess you would really like to get 300 points. But I think someone who has a bit more experience in printing on rolling paper will help me :) And I know at least 2 hot fixes on how to solve this issue ;)

Comment: Nah, I'm not actually, I just couldn't post an image without posting it as an answer. If you've already got 2 solutions, post either/both of them and award the correct answer to yourself. I'd certainly be interested in seeing a solution to this curly question.

Comment: The reason why I post this, is that I am not very confident with the solution. I will not award to myself, so maybe you are the winner :)

Comment: One hot fix is to put the page setup height set to 1cm, which will then make a page of 15cm height to be printed on 15 "virtual" pages - the result is a good paper length of continuous paper, but the downside is obviously very bad preview.

Comment: Did you get solution?